# How to rollback and exit in sqlplus whenever SQL WARNINGS occurs in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am executing multiple script files listed in a file in sqlplus using `@` symbol.

Example:

Consider a script file 'all_scripts.sql' contains the following content.

```
@my_script_1.sql
@my_script_2.sql
@my_script_3.sql
@my_script_4.sql
```

I am executing the file `all_scripts.sql` in sqlplus using `@` symbol. Whenever any error occurred in any one of the files in the 'all_scripts.sql' file, then rollback and exit the sqlplus should happen without executing the following script files. This is achieved using `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK` command which is used as the first command after login the database. This is working fine.

But when a PL/SQL block is compiled with errors, it shows the below message.

> **Warning: Type Body created with compilation errors.**

**In this case, all other script files are also executed. I need to rollback and exit the sqlplus without executing the following script files.**

So, how to rollback and exit in sqlplus whenever sql warning occurs in Oracle PL/SQL?

Comment: A side issue, but your `create type body` (or any `create`) is DDL so commits implicitly even if it fails; so your rollback isn't going to do anything. Stopping anything else executing is still a useful goal, of course.

Comment: By the way, `EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` is OK in Windows but not advisable on Linux systems where the return code is an 8 bit number, as any sqlcode above 255 will overflow giving misleading results. Personally I've never felt the need to capture the sqlcode from a script anyway.